# Summation of primes is giving wrong answer

Tags: c

I just started programming in C and i'm doing exercise from . I'm at  https://projecteuler.net/problem=10 now and i wrote that code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    long int i=0,below=0,a=0;
    long int sum=0;
    printf("belowe number: ");
    scanf("%d",&below);
    int board[below];
    for(i=1;i<below;++i){
        board[i]=0;
    }
    for(i=2;i<below;i++){
        if(board[i]==0){
            sum+=i;
            for(a=2*i;a<=below;a+=i){
                board[a]=1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("sum = %d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that its returning wrong sum (1179908154) instead of (142913828922). Can you tell me where the error is? I'm using [THIS](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sito_Eratostenesa) method to calculate prime numbers.

Comment: You know that there is a long key in the keyboard when you press it, a white space is inserted which makes your code way easier to read. Don't you?

Comment: Maybe you need long long?  How big is long on your system?

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%d",&below);
```

This is not how you read a `long int` (the type of `below` object), use `ld` conversion specifier. Same for your `printf` call.

Comment: `printf("sum = %d",sum);` has the same problem

Comment: @KlasLindbäck thanks, I added a mention to the `printf` call.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple mistakes:

1. You have never Initialized `board[0]`. This array element will contain garbage value.
2. You are accessing `board` array out of bound here:

   `for(a=2*i;a<=below;a+=i)
   {
               board[a]=1;  //Here Index 'a' can be equal to  below
   }`
3. As pointed out by @ouah